# php реферальная система

Tags: php, sql

Пишу многоуровневую реферальную систему с рангами. Т.е. 5 уровней и ранги за кол пригласивших, у каждого разный процент отчислений. При регистрации заношу id пригласившего рефералу. Далее при покупке рефералом пакета делаю отчисления

```
$dataRef = $this->db->column('SELECT ref FROM accounts WHERE id = :id', 
      ['id' => $data['uid']]);
        if ($dataRef === false) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($dataRef != 0) {
            $refSum = round((($data['amount'] * 15) / 100), 2);
            $params = [
                'sum' => $refSum,
                'id' => $dataRef,
            ];
            $this->db->query('UPDATE accounts SET refBalance = refBalance + :sum WHERE id = :id', $params);
```

Потом по цепочке человеку на уровень выше

```
$dataRef2 = $this->db->column('SELECT ref FROM accounts WHERE id = :id', ['id' => $dataRef]);
                if ($dataRef2 === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if ($dataRef2 != 0) {
                    $refSum = round((($data['amount'] * 10) / 100), 2);
                    $params = [
                        'sum' => $refSum,
                        'id' => $dataRef2,
                    ];
                    $this->db->query('UPDATE accounts SET refBalance = refBalance + :sum WHERE id = :id', $params);
```

Вопрос можно ли как-то сделать это элегантнее и сократить код? А то у меня так будет 40 таких кусков, для проверки на уровень и ранг.
Первый id это SESSION id реферала , который купил пакет, отправляется методом post в платежку. amount это цена тарифа тоже при покупке уходит
MySQL 5v

Comment: во первых это можно делать в цикле, беря процент отчислений из какого нибудь массива. Во вторых наверняка можно вообще в один запрос сделать, без задействования php. Правда для этого надо знать какая БД, точную структуру таблиц и откуда берется $data[amount]

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример , вот таблица  accounts    https://pastenow.ru/938b56141f10906cb5eee3b0efc98a61    $data[amount] это цена пакета, будет браться из таблицы tarifs при покупке

Comment: Все таки СУБД укажите и версию. в MySQL (до 8.0) придется с переменными извращаться и returning нет. В других СУБД можно нормальными рекурсивными запросами пользоваться и опять же наличие returning позволяет одновременно обновить запись и получить id следующего реферала на следующий цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновить вполне можно одним запросом:

```
update accounts A
  join (
    SELECT @id:=(select ref from accounts where id=@id) id,
           round(@amount * proc / 100, 2) amount
      FROM (
       select @amount:= :AMOUNT, @id:= :ID
      ) init, (
       select 1 N, 15 proc union all select 2, 10 union all
       select 3, 8 union all select 4, 5 union all select 5, 3
      ) P
    order by N
  ) N on A.id=N.id and N.id is not null
  set A.refBalance = A.refBalance + N.amount
```

Необходимо передать 2 параметра: сумму начислений и стартовый ID (его реферал первым получит отчисления). В подзапросе `P` задаются по порядку уровней рефералов (`N`) процент (`proc`) отчисления им.

Comment: ох сложноватый синтаксис, т.е его мне вставить как-то так  
     $this->db->query('Ваш запрос', $params); а как мне туда передать

Comment: @KirillDanilenko Ну да, просто написать его в query, а $params это массив `['AMOUNT' => $data['amount'], 'ID' => $data['uid']]` ну и проценты не забыть исправить